# How can you mock a variable inside of python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-unittest

I have a Python class that I'm trying mock a certain variable in my unit test.
Excerpt of my Python class:

```
class something:
    def __init__(self):
        self._commandline = 'dir'

    def run_function(self):
        pass
```

In my unit test I am trying to set the class variable _commandline to something like "dirx" so that when I call run_function() that uses subprocess.run it'll fail and throw a subprocess.CalledProcessError so that I can test my assert.

This is my first time doing TDD please advice if there is a better way of doing this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-assign the `_commandLine` variable.

E.g.

`something.py`:

```py
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self._commandline = 'dir'

    def run_function(self):
        print(self._commandline)
        pass
```

`test_something.py`:

```py
import unittest
from something import Something


class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_run_function(self):
        instance = Something()
        instance._commandline = 'dirx'
        instance.run_function()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
dirx
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```